# Windows Server no option for domain logon

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

EDIT:
Problem solved. Thank you everyone! I reset local admin password and discovered that someone had taken this machine off the domain. Easy fix once the password was reset.

Original:
We are running `Server 2008` to host all of our network drives etc. I need to login using our Domain Administrator account, but when trying to login I'm presented with two local account options and that's it. It will not let me select other to login as domain\administrator

Anybody know how to fix this?

Before you ask: I have inherited this setup from the previous IT person and I do not have the local admin account password.

[image: No Domain Login Options]

Comment: Ask the former admin.

Comment: Log in remotely from a domain client? The server you're showing may not actually be joined to the domain.

Comment: The server is simply not a domain member. Add it to the domain and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this also looks like this machine is not domain joined. So the server correctly only presents the two local accounts that are present on the machine. You need the local admin password to login. Luckily, there is a way to reset this password with the utilman.exe trick.

Mount Windows ISO and boot into it. Press Shift + F10 to open CMD.

```
move C:\Windows\System32\Utilman.exe C:\
copy C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe C:\Windows\System32\Utilman.exe
wpeutil reboot
```

(If the C:\ drive does not show up, you might have to load drivers explicitly via the drvload command).
After reboot, click on the utilman.exe icon. A CMD will now open.

[image]

```
net user Administrator newPassword123
```

You can now login with that new password to your server. After logged in, make sure to revert the steps with utilman.exe again.

```
copy C:\Utilman.exe C:\Windows\System32\Utilman.exe
del C:\Utilman.exe
```

Comment: Thank you Dave.. I actually used Hirens Boot CD and changed local admin password that way. But this little trick is good to know .        After getting into the VM i see that someone has taken it off the Domain and added it to a Workgroup. Why? Hell if i know... But issue is now solved.  Thanks again!